# What is the song that plays when Clovis indirectly orders the Purebloods (Jermiah, Nu) to board their Knighmares in Episode 1?

Tags: music, code-geass

In ep 1, starting from  6:10 minute mark, when Clovis says "its all in the performance", a song that seem to be a duo of piano and violin plays and continues until beyond 7 minute mark while the Jeremiahs group board their Knightmares. I couldnt fidn it anywhere on youtube for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Edit/update: I found the song what is identical to the one I was looking for. It's titled Out of the Ordinary. The one below is somewhat similar to this track, though.
I found one that appears to be similar to the one I was looking for,  it's called Cold Nobility, I suppose it might even be supposed to be  the same song, despite some differences.